# Extract numbers from String - Macro/Excel

Tags: excel, vba, string

I am looking for help on the below 2 instances in Macro & also as a formula. Have to extract the numbers including the comma’s

Situation1:
Cell A1 has

> C160516XXX**164614722,65**

Thinking if we can extract the number by reading from right and until a letter/character appears

Situation2:

Cell B1 has

> 1605080506C**91244,22**FDEC20160413000488//4261997/XXXX/XXXXXXX/XXX/US98268242

Is it possible to extract the numbers hidden between the first and the second letter/character?

Comment: This has been asked numerous times here on SO or you can search google.

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea. For Situation 1, loop backwards until you encounter a non-numeric character. Use `IsNumeric(Mid(str, index, 1))` to grab a 1-character string and test whether it is numeric. Then, store the number of iterations `n` til value was found. Use `Right(str, n)` to grab the substring of the last n characters of the string.

For Situation 2, loop forwards, storing the indices of the first and second non-numeric characters, `x1` and `x2`. Then, use `Mid(str, x1+1, x2-x1-1)` to get the substring between your first and second non-numeric character.

Here is an example VBA implementation that will put your answers in C1 and D1:

```
Sub getSubstrings()
    Dim str1 As String
    Dim str2 As String
    Dim char As String
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim x1 As Integer
    Dim x2 As Integer

    str1 = Cells(1, 1).Value 'A1
    str2 = Cells(1, 2).Value 'B1

    'Situation 1
    For i = Len(str1) To 1 Step -1
        char = Mid(str1, i, 1)
        If Not IsNumeric(char) And char <> "," Then
            n = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    Cells(1, 3).Value = Right(str1, Len(str1) - n) 'write answer to C1

    'Situation 2
    x1 = 0
    x2 = 0
    For i = 1 To Len(str2)
        char = Mid(str2, i, 1)
        If Not IsNumeric(char) And char <> "," Then
            If x1 = 0 Then
                x1 = i  'set first index
            Else
                x2 = i  'set second
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Cells(1, 4).Value = Mid(str2, x1 + 1, x2 - x1 - 1)
End Sub
```

FYI most people on SO will not give you a full code implementation, but I had nothing better to do. There is also likely a Excel command solution, but they normally don't handle "character classes" (non-numeric but not comma). I suggest using this code as a template to think about future VBA solutions. I show you here how to access cells, loop over data, and write conditional statements. Please do some research online as well to become more familiar.

Comment: thanks for your response, I am not an expert in coding.. is it possible for you to assist

Comment: Sure, have you tried anything yet? Welcome to StackOverflow btw! SO is not a code-for-me service; rather, it encourages you to do some research on your own and provides help when you get stuck. If you haven't coded in VBA yet, I would recommend looking online for a tutorial to get you started.

Comment: =MID(C2, FIND("C",C2)+1, FIND(",",C2) - FIND("C",C2) +2 ) @Sean Scott

I have tried the below for situation 2

However I realised that some of my data do not have commas and a few variations. I am looking at combining FIND and OR functions. 

C45227,49DIV
D45227,49FV

Comment: Did this do what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

For

C160516XXX**164614722,65**

you can use Excel formulas, For example `MID()` and `SEARCH()` can be combined to give you following result.

**164614722,65**

put this where you want result `=MID(A1,SEARCH("xxx",A1,1)+3,SEARCH("xxx",A1,1)+100)`